# Which is correct "Do you know {if/will} linear algebra {will be/be} offered...", "If/will be" or "will/be"?

Tags: questions, conditional-constructions

I feel confused which one of the following is correct?

> 1. Do you know **if** linear algebra **will be** offered in the following semester?
> 2. Do you know **will** linear algebra **be** offered in the following semester?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second sentence is incorrect.
The sentence after "Do you know (if)" should not be in question form.